# The performClick () method does not work, I get an error

Tags: java, android

I have 2 java class

I want to click btntwo when btn is clicked.

When I click on the button named btn I want to click the button named btn two automatically.
But I get an error.

MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn =  findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //   Log.e("test","testone");
                final Main2Activity main2Activity = new Main2Activity();

                main2Activity.btntwo
                        .post(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                main2Activity.btntwo.performClick();

                            }
                        });            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main2Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btntwo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        btntwo =  findViewById(R.id.btntwo);

        btntwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("test","testtwo");

            }
        });

}
}
```

**I'm getting an error**

```
2020-05-16 17:06:35.238 8529-8529/com.qarocotwo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.qarocotwo.myapplication, PID: 8529
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.Button.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
        at com.qarocotwo.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

why am i getting an error?
where am i doing wrong
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the object of the Main2Activity class in the wrong place.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    Main2Activity main2Activity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn =  findViewById(R.id.btn);
       main2Activity = new Main2Activity();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //   Log.e("test","testone");

                main2Activity.btntwo
                        .post(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                main2Activity.btntwo.performClick();

                            }
                        });            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by the following:

In MainActivity:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

       // Launch the Main2Activity using startActivity and pass the extra to 
       // indicate that ‘btn’ is clicked

    });
```

In Main2Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    //get intent extras, if the extras contains an indicator which is sent 
    //from MainActivity, perform click on ‘btntwo’
   …
 }
```

Comment: I couldn't fully understand.
Are you telling me to do this?                                                           startActivity(main2Activity);
 private void startActivity(Main2Activity main2Activity) {
            }                                                                                                                                it does not work

Comment: In MainActivity: btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Indicator", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: In Main2activity: Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            if (b.containsKey("Indicator"))
                btntwo.performClick();
        }

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
however, this method works when the class is extends with AppCompatActivity.
If my class is fragment, startActivity (intent); gives an error.
I created my MainActivity and Main2Activity classes to be examples.
The classes in my project are actually being extends with fragment.
I'm sorry for the mistake.
I will change my sample codes to fragment.